# Highchart GMT and one hour offset

Tags: javascript, highcharts, codeigniter-2

I'm using Highchart and codeigniter (not relevant in this case I think). I have some couple of (date,data) and i use them in a highchart spline chart.
My pb come from GMT. I'm using timestamp format (store in this format in my MySQL database) but I have one hour less in my chart.

For example :
this timestamp **1364166000000** give me with [epoch website](http://www.epochconverter.com/) :
GMT: Sun, 24 Mar 2013 23:00:00 GMT
Your time zone: lundi 25 mars 2013 00:00:00 GMT+1

But my chart give me 23:00:00. It don't care of my local GMT. What is my error in my date management ?

Thanks for your help on this

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried setting `global.useUTC` to `false`? By default, Highcharts will show all dates in UTC (hence the 23:00 time value you are seeing).

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC: false
    }
});
```

See the documentation [here](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#global.useUTC) and the corresponding demos.